# Nested JSON to HTML table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

There might be an idiotic mistake in my code, but I just haven't found the answer yet. I'm using JSON data from http://rata.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/live-trains/[trainnumber] which is an external site.

My objective is to get data from array inside JSON array to a simple HTML table, in this case stationShortCode, type, commercialTrack and scheduledTime from all  timeTableRows -arrays. JSON data looks like this:

```
    [{"trainNumber":9707,
  "departureDate":"2015-06-03",
  "operatorUICCode":10,
  "operatorShortCode":"vr",
  "trainType":"HL",
  "trainCategory":"Commuter",
  "commuterLineID":"H",
  "runningCurrently":false,
  "cancelled":false,
  "version":4295000475,
  "timeTableRows":[  
      {  
        "stationShortCode":"HKI",
        "stationUICCode":1,
        "countryCode":"FI",
        "type":"DEPARTURE",
        "trainStopping":true,
        "commercialStop":true,
        "commercialTrack":"6",
        "cancelled":false,
        "scheduledTime":"2015-06-03T14:48:00.000Z"
     },
     {  
        "stationShortCode":"PSL",
        "stationUICCode":10,
        "countryCode":"FI",
        "type":"ARRIVAL",
        "trainStopping":true,
        "commercialStop":true,
        "commercialTrack":"3",
        "cancelled":false,
        "scheduledTime":"2015-06-03T14:52:30.000Z"
     }, and 5 to 50 timeTableRows more.
```

json.php, which gets the train number from $_GET, looks like this

```
    <?php
$juna = $_GET["juna"];?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php
$juna = $_GET["juna"];
echo $juna;?></h1>
<script>
$.ajax({
url: 'http://rata.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/live-trains/<?php echo $juna;?>',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    $(row).appendTo('table.data');
    row = '';
    for (var i in data.timeTableRows) {
        row += '<tr id="' + i + '">';
        row += '<td>' + data.timeTableRows[i].stationShortCode + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + data.timeTableRows[i].commercialTrack + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + data.timeTableRows[i].scheduledTime + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + data.timeTableRows[i].type + '</td>';
        row += '</tr>';
    }
    $(row).appendTo('table.data');
},
});
</script><table id="data"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure that there is/are some idiotic mistake(s), but I just can't see them myself.

Comment: You might want to update the version of jQuery, that's a really old version.

Comment: Of course, that was just the first one to copypaste. Planning to use local version on server.

Comment: Don't copy paste such an old version. Just download a copy from the jquery website. You could be trying to use features that don't exist in that old version. A lot has changed between v1.5 and v1.11.

Comment: So, now using local jquery-1.11.3.min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i wrote the whole script again from the scratch, with a little twist. 
JSON parse script is now

```
function myFunction(response) {
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
var i;
var out = "<table><tr><td>Juna</td><td>Asema</td><td>Pysähtyy</td><td>Aikataulu</td><td>Raide</td></tr>";

for(j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
for(i = 0; i < obj[j].timeTableRows.length; i++) {
out += "<tr><td>" +
obj[j].trainNumber +
"</td><td>" +
obj[j].timeTableRows[i].stationShortCode +
"</td><td>" +
obj[j].timeTableRows[i].commercialStop +
"</td><td>" +
obj[j].timeTableRows[i].scheduledTime +
"</td></tr>";
}
}
out += "</table>"
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

And I also added the first trainNumber column for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to append to a table with a class of `data`, but you don't have one. Your table has an id of `data`, change `$(row).appendTo('table.data');` to `$(row).appendTo('table#data');`

Comment: Changed to table#data, and also removed the upper mistakenly put `$(row).appendTo('table.data');`, but still not showing the table.

Comment: Add in `console.log(row)` just before `$(row).appendTo('table#data');` and check the console to see if the HTML is in row.